# Entity Framework Core: Combine owned properties with inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Given are the following classes:

```
public class Rule
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public RuleAction Action { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RuleAction
{
}

public class RuleAction1 : RuleAction
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RuleAction2 : RuleAction
{
    public decimal Percent { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map these classes to the following table layout. I use Entity Framework Core Preview 2.

```
Table "Rule"
  - Id
  - Filter
  - ActionDiscriminator
  - Value // only set if the object in Action is typeof(RuleAction1)
  - Percent // only set if the object in Action is typeof(RuleAction2)
```

The important part is that "Action" is not mapped to a separate table. I know i can map the property as a "Owned property" like described in this article (OwnsOne): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-2/ but this dosn't seem to work in combination with inheritance, at least i couldn't find an example.

Anybody knows how to combine owned properties with inheritance?

Comment: Owned types don't support inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do something like this:

```
 public class RuleAction1 : RuleAction
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public decimal Percent { get; set; } = null;
    }

    public class RuleAction2 : RuleAction
    {
        public decimal Percent { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

That way those value match the table schema but just default to null values.  Or you could do something like this:

```
    public abstract class RuleAction
    {
        public string Value { get; set; } = null;
        public decimal Percent { get; set; } = null;
    }

    public class RuleAction1 : RuleAction
    {            
    }

    public class RuleAction2 : RuleAction
    {            
    }
```

I could be way off, sorry if this is only slowing you down.